# Finding the minimum node and then returning the next minimum natural value that's not in the BST

Tags: recursion, binary-search-tree, minimum, avl-tree

So I have a problem and I have the Algorithm for it, but I just can't seem to be able to turn it into code in C.

Problem: Given an AVL tree, return the next minimum natural value that's not in the tree.

Example: if 2 is the minimum in the tree, I should find out whether or not 3 is one of the nodes in the tree, if it is not, I should return the value 3, if it is, I should see if 4 is in the tree, and so on...

Algorithm to the problem that works in O(logn) (when n is the Number of nodes found in the tree):

first, we check if node->size = node -> key - TreeMinimum
if yes, go to the right side of the tree.
if no, then go to the left.
when we reach NULL, we should return the value of the last node we visited plus 1.
SIZE of the node is the number of nodes that are under this node, including the node itself.
I wrote this code in c but it doesn't seem to work :

```
int next_missing( AVLNodePtr tnode )
{
    int x,y;
    if(tnode==NULL)
    {
        return (tnode->key)+1;
    }
    if(tnode->size == tnode->key - FindMin(tnode))
         x = next_missing(tnode->child[1]);
    if(tnode->size != tnode->key - FindMin(tnode))
         y = next_missing(tnode->child[0]);

     if(x>y) return y;
    else return x;
}
```

Any help/tips on how to fix the code would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you accept pseudo code?

Comment: Yes. @YoungDev.